# Eager-loading with many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :shops, through: :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :thing
  belongs_to :shop
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :things, through: :products
end
```

Shop sales many things. Every shop has its own page with the list of its things. Products table has shop_id, thing_id, things quantity and thing price.
Here is controller:

```
def show
  @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
end
```

And view:

```
<% @shop.things.each do |thing| %>
  <%= link_to thing.name, shop_thing_path(id: thing.id, shop_id: @shop.id) %><br>
  <%= thing.products.find_by(shop_id: @shop.id).price %><br>
  <%= thing.products.find_by(shop_id: @shop.id).quantity %>
<% end %>
```

I can't understand how to eager load this right. Now i get N * 2 queries (N = things count):

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."thing_id" = ? AND "products"."shop_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`def show
  @shop = Shop.includes(:things).find(params[:id])
end`

Here is the documentation related to eager loading.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: Maybe i'm a bit stupid, but neither `Shop.find(params[:id]).include(:things)` nor `Shop.find(params[:id]).includes(:things)` work (undefined method). I tried `Shop.includes(:things).find(params[:id])` but that doesn't work too.

Comment: While this question may answer the question, it is unclear why it does. Please help the OP by explaining what the proposed solution causes to happen differently.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to go from another point and use @products instead of @shop.things:

**Controller:**

```
def show
  @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
  @products = @shop.products.includes(:thing).joins(:thing)
end
```

**View**

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to product.thing.name, shop_thing_path(id: product.thing_id, shop_id: product.shop_id) %></td>
    <td><%= product.price %></td>
    <td><%= product.quantity %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Now that works. But i still can't understand why

```
def show
  @shop = Shop.includes(:things).find(params[:id])
end
```

doesn't work.